# radioButton.Checked_Changed event firing too many times

Tags: c#, events, radio-button, groupbox

**Overview:**  I have a groupBox with 3 radio buttons in it.  I have code that is supposed to happen upon changing the radio button selected... for instance a message box asking "are you sure" only a bit more specific to each radio button.  choices are Open, Close, and ReOpen.  message boxes pop upon clicking close and reopen asking are you sure you want to Close and are you sure you want to reopen.

**Problem:**  The way it is currently working I am getting the message popped up twice for each change because it is registering the changed event for checked = true on the one selected and again on the checked = false for the one that used to be selected.

I would assume there is a better way to do this but I am not sure which event to use from the groupBox so that there is only one change event and not 2.  here is a sample of the code I am using

```
private void statusChanged()
{
    DialogResult choice;
    if (formLoading == false)
    {
        btnSave.Enabled = true;
        if (optStatusOpen.Checked == true)
        {
            optStatusOpen.Text = "Opened";
            optStatusClosed.Text = "Close";
            optStatusReOpened.Text = "Re-Open";
            optStatusClosed.Checked = false;
            optStatusClosed.Enabled = true;
            optStatusReOpened.Checked = false;
            optStatusReOpened.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (optStatusClosed.Checked == true)
        {
            choice = MessageBox.Show("You've selected to close claim: " + txtCaimNumber.Text.ToUpper() + ". Continue?",
                                     "Close Claim Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (choice == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (closeClaim(txtClaimNumber.Text.ToUpper()) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Claim successfully closed");
                    txtClaimNumber.Enabled = true;
                    optStatusClosed.Text = "Closed";
                    optStatusOpen.Text = "Open";
                    optStatusOpen.Checked = false;
                    optStatusOpen.Enabled = false;
                    optStatusReOpened.Text = "Re-Open";
                    optStatusReOpened.Checked = false;
                    optStatusReOpened.Enabled = true;
                    dtpCloseDate.Enabled = true;
                    txtClaimNumber.Focus();
                }
            }
            else//choice == no
            {
                formLoading = true;
                if (curStatus == 0) //open
                {
                    optStatusOpen.Checked = true;
                    optStatusClosed.Checked = false;
                    optStatusReOpened.Checked = false;
                }
                else if (curStatus == 2)//reopened
                {
                    optStatusOpen.Checked = false;
                    optStatusClosed.Checked = false;
                    optStatusReOpened.Checked = true;
                    dtpReopenDate.Enabled = true;
                }
                else // curStatus = 1 
                {
                    optStatusOpen.Checked = false;
                    optStatusClosed.Checked = true;
                    optStatusReOpened.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else //ReOpened.checked = true
        {
            curStatus = 3;
            choice = MessageBox.Show("You've selected to reopen claim: " + txtClaimNumber.Text.ToUpper() + ". Continue?",
                                     "Close Claim Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (choice == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (reOpenClaim(txtClaimNumber.Text.ToUpper()) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Claim successfully ReOpened");
                    txtClaimNumber.Enabled = true;
                    optStatusOpen.Text = "Open";
                    optStatusReOpened.Text = "Re-Opened";
                    optStatusClosed.Text = "Close";
                    optStatusClosed.Enabled = true;
                    optStatusOpen.Checked = false;
                    optStatusOpen.Enabled = false;
                    txtClaimNumber.Focus();
                    dtpReopenDate.Enabled = true;
                    dtpReopenDate.Checked = true;                        
                }
            }
            else//choice == no
            {
                formLoading = true;
                optStatusOpen.Checked = false;
                optStatusClosed.Checked = true;
                optStatusReOpened.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method is sitting in the Checked_Changed event for each of the radio buttons like this:

```
private void optStatusClosed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked == true) //added this line to solve the problem
        statusChanged();
}
```

Comment: you could try this: if(!((RadioButton)sender).IsChecked) return;

Comment: A global variable seems the best solution for your problem. There is no way to tell whether the given selection was performed by the user or by your code and thus the corresponding event is triggered every time you perform a selection via code. Usually I rely on a boolean flag but as far as here you are performing various "checks" together, I guess that an integet would do a better job (e.g., timesToWait = 2 right before checking two buttons). I was writing an answer but apparently you found what you were looking for (I guess that on this line because don't see any other way through).

Comment: I have read your last edit and I am not sure that this solves your problem (you have to call the method in both cases button being checked or not, isn't it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `statusChanged()` to be called only for radio button which is checked right now, you can check `IsChecked` property of radio button in your handler -

```
private void optStatusClosed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
    {
       statusChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: forgive me if I seem a bit the Novice but am I correct in assuming that the if statement will only allow access to the statusChanged() method when it is checked == true not checked == false?

Comment: So I tried you solution and the .IsChecked was not available although the .Checked == true option was.  I am checking this one as the answer because you helped me find what I was looking for.  I am editing my question to reflect the correct answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer and yes `.Checked` is sufficient. It is equivalent to `.Checked==true`

Comment: I am not sure if I a missed something but I am afraid this is not a solution for what the OP was looking for: he wants the statusChanged method being called every time a button is clicked (checked or not). What he does not want is to call it when the selection is performed by the code, just by the user. Your solution does not address this problem.

Comment: @varocarbas - OP has accepted the answer. So, i guess he wants this only.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I saw that, that's why I stopped writing my own answer. But I think that he didn't tested the code properly (I did test it and saw the problems I am referring). Anyway... I wanted just to highlight the issue just to make sure (have explained everything via comment, just in case the OP (or anyone else) needs further help).